# How do I prompt users to exit and restart program if they say no

Tags: python, python-3.7

Could someone please help on how to prompt users to exit, and if they say no, to go  back and rerun the program? I'm having an absolute head ache with it and the internet hasn't helped.

This is my code:

```
print("Hello, this program will ask for two numbers, then show the product 
of those numbers that many times")

value = input("Please enter number")

value = int(value)

value2 = input("Please enter a second number")

value2 = int(value2)

for i in range(value*value2):
    print(value*value2)

    while True:
        answer = input("Do you wih to exit? Enter Yes or No:")
        if answer in ('No', 'Yes'):
            break
        print ("Invalid input.")
    if answer == 'No':
        continue
    else:
        print ("Goodbye")
        break
```

It's just multiplication then displaying the sum as many times as itself, but I can't figure out how to prompt users to exit, then run through the program again if they say no. I've heard of putting the entire code in a loop, and I've tried, to no avail. Could I please get some help?

Comment: To clarify, when you say "display as many times as itself" should imputs 5, 6 print 30 to the console window 30 times?

Comment: yeah, basically.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as a recursive function and do a loop when the user answers No.

For example:

```
def ask():
    print("Hello, this program will ask for two numbers, then show the product of those numbers that many times")

    value = input("Please enter number")

    value = int(value)

    value2 = input("Please enter a second number")

    value2 = int(value2)

    for i in range(value * value2):
        print(value * value2)
    answer = input("Do you wih to exit? Enter Yes or No:")
    if answer not in ('No', 'Yes'):
        print("Invalid input.")
    if answer == 'No':
        ask()
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
ask()
```

Comment: Although this is completely viable, the recursion  limit is always a small caveat (depending on the expected number of uses, of course).

Comment: Recursion is *not* a good choice when your functionality is actually a `while` concept.

Comment: @Prune you're right. Got rid of the `while` in my edit.

Comment: You're still using recursion to run a `while`-type idea.  There's no advantage to pushing the call stack deeper on this, and maintaining data from previous calls.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer as written, but without writing a function:
The key here is that you need to loop until the user inputs 'yes'. Your `while` loop will never be false, so you'll prompt forever. Here's another solution (though @Ricky Kim has a much more pythonic answer)

```
answer=""
while answer!= "yes":
    print("Hello, this program will ask for two numbers, then show the product \
    of those numbers that many times")

    value = input("Please enter number")

    value = int(value)

    value2 = input("Please enter a second number")

    value2 = int(value2)

    for i in range(value*value2):
        print(value*value2)
    #use lower so that the user can enter "Yes" or "yes"
    answer = str.lower(input("Do you wih to exit? Enter Yes or No:"))
print ("Goodbye")
```